# Atomic int64_t on ARM Cortex M3

Tags: assembly, arm, atomic

Since my compiler still doesn't support c++11 and std::atomic, I'm forced to implement it manually via ldrex-strex pair.

My question is: what is the correct way to 'atomically' read-modify-write int64_t with ldrex and strex?

Simple solution like this doesn't seem to work (one of STREXW returns 1 all the time):

```
volatile int64_t value;
int64_t temp;

do
{
    int32_t low = __LDREXW( (uint32_t *)&value );
    int32_t high = __LDREXW( ((uint32_t *)&value)+1 );

    temp = (int64_t)low | ( (int64_t)high<<32);
    temp++;    

} while( __STREXW( temp, (uint32_t *)&value) |  __STREXW( temp>>32, ((uint32_t *)&value)+1) );
```

I couldn't find anything about several sequential LDREX or STREX instructions pointing to different addresses in the manual but it seemed to me that it should be allowed.

Otherwise multiple threads would not be able to change two different atomic variables in some scenarios.

Comment: is it GCC? consider GCC built-in atomics?

Comment: GCC for ARM now has support for std::atomic. No, it's not GCC, it's Keil armcc.

Comment: See: [ARM AN321 - Cortex-M memory barriers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0321a/BIHEADII.html).  Atomic is a bit of an overloaded word.  Things can not happen atomically in the universe.  They are atomic versus some set of electronics; mainline/interrupts,  SMP, device on a bus, etc.  What exactly is your problem?  You have to describe it better.

Comment: Additionally, you can use `ldrd` and `strd` with a spinlock and/or structure such as ring-buffers are inherently safe for single reader/writer and have been used for years with mainline/interrupts.  See: Donald Knuth, The Art of computer programming and [Linux kfifo.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/kfifo.h) by Stefani Seibold and others.  I think she did a great job of this implementation, but it relies on some overflow conditions that zealots may not like.

Comment: A single `ldrex` and `strex` maybe used on multiple address locations.  This is called the reserve granule.  According to this [arm technical support article](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka16180.html), the reserve granule is 4GB or the entire address space.  So, you just need to use a normal `load/store` for the 2nd 32bit location.  However, this is probably very system specific and it is entirely possible that depending on memory type/SOC, it will not work.

Comment: @artlessnoise I'm afraid I don't understand what do you mean by "single ldrex and strex maybe used on multiple address locations". Both ldrex and strex take only one address as an argument. Or do you mean I can read one half of uint64 by ldrex and the other by ldr since any strex will cause exclusive reservation to fail?

Comment: Correct, if the stars align, it is possible to have ldrex/ldr and str/strex.  But it is probably just simpler to use a spin lock for both.  Ie, use a 32 bit value as a lock (via `ldrex`, `strex`) and use `ldrd` and `strd` for the data.  As `strex` can fail, it is already like a spinlock.  Still `ldrex` and `strex` and *atomic* to the CPU and the AHB peripherals can ignore them.  So you should use this for pure code problems/issues (multi-cpu, interrupt/mainline, or pre-emptive OS thread/task/processes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will never work, because you cannot nest exclusives that way. Implementation-wise, the Cortex-M3 local exclusive monitor doesn't even keep track of an address - [the exclusive reservation granule is the entire address space](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100165_0201_00_en/ric1417175928887.html) - so the assumption of tracking each word separately is already invalid. However, you don't even need to consider any implementation details, because the architecture already explicitly rules out the back-to-back `strex`:

> If two STREX instructions are executed without an intervening LDREX the second STREX returns a status value of 1. This means that:
>
> - Every STREX must have a preceding LDREX associated with it in a given thread of execution.
> - It is not necessary for every LDREX to have a subsequent STREX .

Since Cortex-M3 (and ARMv7-M in general) doesn't have `ldrexd` like ARMv7-A, you'll either have to use a separate lock to control all accesses to the variable, or just disable interrupts around the read-modify-write. If at all possible it would really be better to redesign things not to need an atomic 64-bit type in the first place, since you'd still only achieve atomicity with respect to other threads on the same core - you simply cannot make any 64-bit operation atomic from the point of view of an external agent like a DMA controller.

Comment: I was afraid of that. So if I'm getting it right now, _any_ ldrex will reset exclusive monitor for _every other_ ldrex?

Comment: Thank you, now I get it!

Comment: @Amomum From the look of it, v7-M doesn't even have the local/global monitor distinction - it reads like a trimmed-down version of the v7-A local monitor state machine. I'd guess in practice the hardware probably doesn't even bother tracking an address and just clears the exclusive state on any memory access.

Comment: Nope, scratch that, I was just looking in the wrong place. There can be a global monitor for shareable regions, but I doubt most micros implement one.

Comment: what if I use ldrex to get the high 32 bits of uint64 and simple ldr to get the low, always in that order? Won't high 32 bits act like sort-of spinlock for the whole uint64? It won't work for DMA in 32 bit mode though, but it's something.

Comment: @Amomum It's not the load that's the problem, it's the store - if you do `strex; str` you risk getting preempted immediately after the `strex` succeeds, and your stale `str` then unwittingly trashes half of the updated value without knowing it's changed; if you do `str; strex`, then if the `strex` fails due to the value having changed since your `ldrex`, you've already irrevocably trashed the other half of the value (that, or you retry forever because your own `str` itself clears the monitor).

Comment: @Notlikethat My understanding of the reserve granule was that it would not be committed (ie, `str` before `strex`).  ARM has write buffers and L1 cache per CPU.  So, if the `strex` fails, the first `str` doesn't happen... As I understood an ARM paper I had read.   I think my description is technically possible but I am not 100% sure if would work in all (or any cases).  However as the Cortex-M3 are suppose to have a 4GB 'reserve granule', I don't know that this will work.  AXI bus has this signalling to pipeline.  If the `strex` fails, then the L1 cache could be reread from L2 or main memory.

Comment: ... at least this idea would be very useful.  You can manipulate a data structure up to the reserve granule size atomically.  However, it could be that the 'reserve granule' is just  'lock'  redundancy  (so there is only one for the Cortex-M3).  Not quite as useful.  I can not locate the paper any more on ARM's site.

Comment: @artlessnoise Exclusives are not transactional memory - ARM doesn't have that in any form. A non-exclusive store is always a store, regardless of the instructions around it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just look at how gcc does it, and use the same instruction sequences.

gcc 4.8.2 *claims* to implement `std::atomic<int64_t>` with `is_lock_free()` returning true, even with `-mcpu=cortex-m3`.  **Unfortunately, it doesn't really work.  It makes code that doesn't link or doesn't work, because there is no implementation of the helper functions it tries to use**.  (Thanks @Notlikethat for trying it out.)

[Here's the test code I tried](http://goo.gl/xFWrcP).  See an old version of this answer if that link is dead.  I'm leaving this answer around in case the idea is useful for anyone in related cases where gcc *does* make useful code.

Comment: I tried what you suggested with gcc 5.2.1 for arm and got linker error: "e:\gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_2-2015q4-20151219-win32\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\5.2.1\bits/atomic_base.h:514: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'" when creating std::atomic<long long>; std::atomic<int> worked as expected. Seems legit.

Comment: @Amomum: does your gcc install normally work when it needs helper functions from `libgcc.a`?  That's either a gcc bug or an incorrectly-installed compiler problem.  64bit division is likely to call a similar helper function.

Comment: division of uint64_t calls __aeabi_uldivmod as expected. I don't think that was a bug, maybe there really is no way to implement atomic uint64_t? It's perfectly normal for some architectures not to have uint8_t for example (if CHAR_BITS is greater than 8); so I don't think that not having __atomic_fetch_add_8 is that big of a problem.

Comment: @Amomum: I think the `8` there is 8 bytes, because it's calling it for a 64bit fetch_add.

Comment: Eeehm, isn't it obvious? I also get linker error for atomic<double> and it's pretty consistent with Notlikethat's answer - cortex m3 doesn't have ldrexd so maximum size for exclusive load-store is 4 bytes.

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately, GCC happily generating a call doesn't actually mean all that much. I tried throwing your example against a couple of complete ARM toolchains - a bare-metal newlib (arm-none-eabi) doesn't have an `__atomic_fetch_add_8` implementation at all, so fails to link; the glibc (arm-linux-gnueabihf) implementation uses `__sync_fetch_and_add_8`, which in turn relies on the cmpxchg64 helper provided by Linux (which in the absence of `ldrexd` triggers some magic in the return to userspace path to restart if it gets interrupted) - sadly that doesn't apply to Cortex-M3 either.

Comment: @Notlikethat: thanks for testing it.  I was hoping there was another way that you hadn't thought of.  Since it turns out that gcc is full of crap in this case, I removed most of my answer.